# Is there a site that can host adsense and not blocked in China?

Tags: google-adsense

My adsense account is "hosted". I want to host adsense on my own site because blogspot is banned in china.

So which eligible host share

1. 100% revenue
2. Can be seen in china.

I know youtube and and blogspot is a big no no. So what else?

Comment: You should be considering self hosted if you want your site unblocked in China, and even then there's no reassurance that it won't be blocked at a later date.

Comment: But my adsense account is "hosted". That means I can only put adsense ads on some google sites.